# Http 400 from envoy on BAN request

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, varnish, istio, envoyproxy

Istio Newbie here,

I’m doing my first tests with Istio (on version 1.3.0). Most things run nice without much effort.
What I’m having an issue is a service that talks with varnish to clean up the cache. This service makes a HTTP request to every pod behind a headless service and its failing with a HTTP 400 (Bad Request) error. This request uses the HTTP Method “BAN” which I believe is the source of the problem since other request method reach varnish without problems.

As a temporary workaround I changed the port name from http to varnish and everything start working again

I installed istio using the helm chart for 1.3.0:

```
helm install istio install/kubernetes/helm/istio --set kiali.enabled=true --set global.proxy.accessLogFile="/dev/stdout" --namespace istio-system --version 1.3.0
```

Running on GKE 1.13.9-gke.3 and Varnish is version 6.2

Comment: Hi, have you added your internal CIDRs to your [`acl invalidator`](https://foshttpcache.readthedocs.io/en/latest/varnish-configuration.html)? [Check this example](https://github.com/api-platform/demo/blob/master/api/docker/varnish/conf/default.vcl#L22-L25).

Comment: Yeah I have, varnish BAN commands work perfectly without using istio. The request gets answerded by isito envoy, It's not reaching varnish.

Comment: Can you share your Istio routing configuration in the question?

Comment: There is no particular istio routing created.

Comment: Hi, I replicated it and got it working just by adding the ACL for BAN. Note that I'm hitting the service instead of the pods so I added the service CIDR, from which Varnish should be expecting the BAN request. Another notable thing is that I'm using permissive mTLS. Maybe you can check that as well.

Comment: Hi @yyyyahir thanks for the follow up, but I have to insist that my problem is not with  varnish but with istio. If I remove istio everything works, ( I have that ACL setup for the correct CIDR). The problem only rises when I have istio sidecar besides varnish.

Comment: Added detailed replication as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it working using Istio without mTLS using the following definitions:

**ConfigMap**

Just allowing the pod and service CIDRs for BAN requests and expecting them to come from the Varnish service FQDN.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: varnish-configuration
data:
  default.vcl: |
    vcl 4.0;

    import std;

    backend default {
      .host = "varnish-service";
      .port = "80";      
    }

    acl purge {
        "localhost";
        "10.x.0.0"/14; #Pod CIDR
        "10.x.0.0"/16; #Service CIDR
    }

    sub vcl_recv {
            # this code below allows PURGE from localhost and x.x.x.x

            if (req.method == "BAN") {
                    if (!client.ip ~ purge) {
                            return(synth(405,"Not allowed."));
                    }
                    return (purge);
            }
    }
```

**Deployment**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: varnish
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: varnish
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: varnish
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: varnish
        image: varnish:6.3
        ports:        
        - containerPort: 80
          name: varnish-port
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent        
        volumeMounts:
        - name: varnish-conf
          mountPath: /etc/varnish
      volumes:
      - name: varnish-conf
        configMap:
          name: varnish-configuration
```

**Service**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: varnish-service
  labels:
    workload: varnish
spec:
  selector:
    app: varnish
  ports:    
    - name: varnish-port
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

After deploying these, you can run a cURL enabled pod:

```
kubectl run bb-$RANDOM --rm -i --image=yauritux/busybox-curl --restart=Never --tty -- /bin/sh
```

And then, from the `tty` try curling it:

```
curl -v -X BAN http://varnish-service
```

From here, either you'll get `200 purged` or `405 Not allowed`. Either way, you've hit the Varnish pod across the mesh.

Your issue might be related to mTLS in your cluster. You can check if it's enabled by issuing this command*:

```
istioctl authn tls-check $(k get pod -l app=varnish -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) varnish-service.default.svc.cluster.local
```

**The command assumess that you're using the definitions shared in this post. If not, you can adjust accordingly.*

I tested this running GKE twice: One with open source Istio via Helm install and another using the Google managed Istio installation (in permissive mode).

Comment: Well I think I see the difference now, you have "protocol: TCP" on your service definition and I was using "protocol: http". Sorry for not posting the complete configuration the first time